# Single characters don't left-justify using format in Java?

Tags: java, string, format

A problem I'm having in my programming class is asking me to make a pattern like this:
[image: pattern4]

I used the following code:

```
public static void ch5ex18c() {
    System.out.println("Pattern C");
    String num = "6 5 4 3 2 1";
    for (int count = 10; count >= 0; count-=2){
        System.out.printf("%-10s", num.substring(count, 11) + "\n");
    }
}
```

and I got everything to print out well except the first number line:
[image: problem]

I know I can fix this using an if statement, but I'd just prefer not to and I want to know why it would do this in the first place.

Comment: try `System.out.printf("%10s%n", num.substring(count, 11));`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your new lines are inserted before extra spaces ("1\n" + spaces), you need to remove the minus sign (that justifies left) and make some minor math alterations.

```
1\n spaces (shown on next line to make it seem like your justifying right
2 1\n spaces
```

and so on